# Elementary Cardinal Arithmetic question from Jech's "Set Theory"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Exercise 5.19 in Jech's "Set Theory"

> If $\alpha \lt \omega_1 $ then prove $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_1} = \aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_0}\cdot2^{\aleph_1}$

I have no idea how to even start with this type of question (but I am sure it will help me with a later question which I am struggling with which I cannot ask here, as it is graded).

The latter half of Chapter 5 is littered with theorems but scanning each to find something usable has not been the most logical approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_0},2^{\aleph_1}\le\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_1}$, so $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_0}\cdot2^{\aleph_1}=\max\left\{\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_0},2^{\aleph_1}\right\}\le\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_1}$.

For the opposite inequality we can use **Theorem** $\mathbf{5.20}$.

- If $\alpha\le 1$, $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}$.

Now assume that $\alpha>1$.

- If there is a $\beta<\alpha$ such that $\aleph_\beta^{\aleph_1}\ge\aleph_\alpha$, then $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_\beta^{\aleph_1}$. This means that we can use induction on $\alpha$ to handle this case.
- If $\aleph_\beta^{\aleph_1}<\aleph_\alpha$ for all $\beta<\alpha$, and $\operatorname{cf}\aleph_\alpha>\aleph_1$, then $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_\alpha=\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_0}$.
- If $\aleph_\beta^{\aleph_1}<\aleph_\alpha$ for all $\beta<\alpha$, and $\operatorname{cf}\aleph_\alpha\le\aleph_1$, then $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_\alpha^{\operatorname{cf}\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_0}$.